# Validate an URL

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

Currently, I am using Angular 5. I tried to validate an URL as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <input formControlName="s_url" type="url" class="form-control" id="kk" placeholder="url">
  <error-display [displayError]="isValid('s_url')" errMsg="This field is required!"></error-display>
</div>
```

In `validate.ts` file, I have this pattern:

```
s_url: new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern("/^(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/")
]),
```

But with the pattern, error message is shown even when  a correct url is typed.

Comment: when you pass a regex as a param for Validators.pattern(regex), you need to scape the back-slashes. I the case of your example, it should look like this: ^(http[s]?:\\/\\/){0,1}(www\\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\\.]{0,1}. The regex I use for urls looks like this: Validators.pattern("^(https|ftp|http|ftps):\\/\\/([a-z\\d_]+\\.)?(([a-zA-Z\\d_]+)(\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))(\\/[a-zA-Z\\d_\\%\\-=\\+]+)*(\\?)?([a-zA-Z\\d=_\\+\\%\\-&\\{\\}\\:]+)?")

Answer (score 36):

You can try this way, by slightly modifying and separating your regex:

```
const reg = '(https?://)?([\\da-z.-]+)\\.([a-z.]{2,6})[/\\w .-]*/?';
...
Validators.pattern(reg)
```

From my own experience the quotes (`"`) and slashes (`/`) can sometimes cause issues with the regex when passed directly into `.pattern()`

---

Here is a working [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3e9qyb)

Comment: It does not validate URLs with query parms like `http://demosite.com/#/admin/project/project-details?id=34`

Comment: It was not the object of the consultation. Open a new thread.

Comment: I recommend following regexp, more complete (include urls with query params) `var URL_REGEXP = /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d.+-]*:\/*(?:\w+(?::\w+)?@)?[^\s/]+(?::\d+)?(?:\/[\w#!:.?+=&%@\-/]*)?$/;` copied from angularjs source code (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/ffb6b2fb56d9ffcb051284965dd538629ea9687a)

Comment: I just tried a random url from google images, seems your solution is not valid for example
https://www.snopes.com/tachyon/2020/03/ss_corona_beer.jpg?resize=865,452

Comment: @VictorDias example works for ip addresses too. Ex. http://102.25.36.24

Comment: How should be the regex if I want to force https?

Answer (score 16):

I think this regex is more complete:

```
const urlRegex = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/;
this.form = this.fb.group({
      s_url: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(urlRegex)]],
    });
```

Please for pattern check [here](https://www.regextester.com/94502)

Comment: **%** is a valid character and often used with encoded string containing special characters. The regex would be better as /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?%#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/

Comment: This doesn't work with unicode characters like ü and ä which are currently supported in domain names.

Comment: Finally The perfect regex! Also thanks @hellimac

Comment: Perfect ! Must say I tried this one with the Chat GPT but his answer wasn't good.

Answer (score 11):

Depending on your requirements, for example, if you don't want to deal with \ maintain a`RegExp` for an URL, you could delegate the work to the browser's built-in form validation facility.

It could be implemented like this:

```
const control: HTMLInputElement = document.createElement("input");
control.type = "url";
control.value = value;
const isValid: boolean = control.checkValidity();
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also make use of the URL API, which has 95% support at the time of writing this answer. See the browser support [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=url)

```js
urlValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl) => {
    let validUrl = true;

    try {
      new URL(control.value)
    } catch {
      validUrl = false;
    }

    return validUrl ? null : { invalidUrl: true };
  }

  searchControl = this.fb.control(null, this.urlValidator);
```

Comment: This does not appear to take protocols into consideration at all.

Comment: http:eca.com give me as valid url

Comment: @JamesParker What do you mean? Could you give an example of what you would consider an invalid URL that is being returned as a valid one? Thanks

Comment: @realappie what James said is that your approach does not validate if there is no http or https.

Comment: @JamesParker @AFetter it is odd that the `URL` class accepts strings with a colon and no slashes, but it would seem that the browser (at least edge Chrome) accepts those in `href` attributes and typed in the address bar as well. For example, in either place, `http:example.com` seems to go to the correct page. This approach also seems much less brittle than a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Works in all browsers with **new URL()** Standard Url validator
Creates and returns a URL object referencing the URL specified using an absolute URL string, or a relative URL string and a base URL string.

```
static url(value) {
    let valid = true;
    try {
        if (value) {
           let validUrl =  new URL(value);
           if(validUrl.host == "" && validUrl.origin == "null"){
            valid = false;
           }
        }
    } catch {
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid ? null : { invalidUrl: true };
}
```

Comment: This won't work as a validator function in current angular versions. It should take the `FormControl` as its argument, and get the string from `control.value`. Also, is there any foreseeable scenario in which the `URL` constructor would return without error, but leave host as null? None of the test strings I've tried did that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this easy approach..

install this library.

```
npm install ng2-validation --save
```

Don't forget this inject this.
In your app.module.ts import this to your import array

```
import { CustomFormsModule } from 'ng2-validation'
```

And in your import array,

```
imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, CustomFormsModule],
```

Then modify your code like below

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <input formControlName="s_url" type="url" class="form-control" id="kk" url placeholder="url">

  <div *ngIf="imageUrl.touched && imageUrl.invalid" >
     <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.required"> This field is required!</div>
     <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.url"> invalid URL </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: outdated, do not use it. updated last time 7 years ago

Answer (score 1):

I tried a half dozen different regexes on a URL I know is valid and none of them worked. But the browser already needs to be able to parse URLs, so I just created a custom validator function with that API, like so:

```
export class CustomValidators {
  static validUrl: ValidatorFn = (control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null  => {
    try {
      let str = control.value;
      if (str.indexOf('://') === -1) {
        str = `https://${str}`;
      }
      const url = new URL(str);
      return null;
    } catch (_) {
      return { invalidUrl: true };
    }
  }
}
```

Then you just use it like one of the built-in validators:

```
this.fb.group({
  url: ['', [CustomValidators.validUrl]]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression **/^(http[s]?://){0,1}(www.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[.]{0,1}/**

it works with all kind OF URL

Comment: Why is "www". hardcoded there? Even the URL of this page does not contain any "www." :-(
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50508712/validate-an-url

Comment: @MarkusSchaber the `{0,1}` following the `(www.)` is the equivalent of saying "with or without `www`"

Comment: @Sean Right. But what's the point then in having the "www." part anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Only for www prefix url like -

- [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) - valid
- google.com - invalid
- http://www.google.com - Invalid

  `(www)\\.([\\da-z.-]+)\\.([a-z.]{2,6})[/\\w .-]*/?`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a regular expression that checks if starts with "https" and not with "http" or any other way, and accepts "queries" and all sort of urls, here it is:

```
/^https:\/*(?:\w+(?::\w+)?@)?[^\s\/]+(?::\d+)?(?:\/[\w#!:.?+=&%@\-\/]*)?$/
```

You can use this page if you want to tweak it to your needs: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * This regex pattern aims to match URLs that start with optional protocols (http://, https://, or ftp://),
 * followed by a domain name, domain extension, and various characters that form the path, query, or fragment part of
 * the URL, as well as allowing `%` as a valid character (for encoded characters).
 *
 * https://regexr.com/7q3qi
 */
const URL_PATTERN: RegExp = /^(?:(?:http|https|ftp):\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-._~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=%]+$/;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this regex

```
/^((http|https|ftp|www):\/\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)(\.)([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]+)/g
```